# Which android ndk version should be used with xamarin.android 6.1

Tags: android, xamarin, android-ndk, xamarin.android

Xamarin does not specify a version for android ndk to use and in the screen shot at [Manual Xamarin.android installation page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/) it shows `r9d` version witch is old. so should i install that specific version or the latest stable version witch is `r12b` at this moment. currently i am using `r10` witch seems to be working currently ....

And also x86 or x64? I am on windows8.1 X64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Xamarin.Android` Version: 6.1.99.224 is using `android-ndk-r10d`.

The current `xamarin-android` build in github is using `android-ndk-r11c`:

Ref : [toolchain.projitems](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/master/build-tools/android-toolchain/android-toolchain.projitems)

Comment: Does that mean we should always follow the Version in this File?  It shows 14B now but today i tried using 18B and it worked

Comment: @batmaci Does not mean it will not work, but it is not the one that it was tested with... so Caveat emptor

Answer (score 1):

For Xamarin.Android 7, you can use NDK r11c, newer version will not be recognized by Xamarin because [files are renamed by google.](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/214040/#Comment_214040)

Comment: In Visual Studio 15 RC, it installs r13b by default. But it's actually a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=48678), it's still the only option to use r11c even for Visual Studio 15 RC.